# Make nested queries in MongoDB 3.0.7

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have **sub-events** belonging to **events** belonging to an **user**, and I know the user's username - how do I get a list of the sub-events?

Is this going in the right direction? Or is it completely off?

```
db.subevents.find({_id: {$in: 
    db.events.find({_id: {$in:
        db.users.find({"username":"userx"},{_id:1})}},{_id:1})}})
```

**Edit:** Here is a sample of the data structure:

```
/* Event */
{
  "_id" : "XjhAqqNBkezKY3mdN",
  "name" : "My event",
  "userId" : "FiKsAAAgBb7cNoPH7"
}
/* Subevent */
{
  "_id" : "WkYAqBXNpJryp7rum",
  "name" : "The subevent",
  "eventId" : "hQXNzX3jbWppbAYFH"
}
/* User */
{
  "_id" : "RTHh5srhLMQp625zF",
  "username" : "userx"
}
```

Comment: could you post a sample of your data structure?

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: It's MongoDB 3.0.7

Comment: you cannon use such syntax in mongo  - but thh will be a nice feature

Comment: @profesor79, this where $lookup comes in to picture isn't it?

Comment: Okay, then how can I retrieve the sub-events belonging to the user?

Comment: try on these lines(not a complete query)  db.subevents.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:"events",localField:"eventid",foreignField:"_id",as:"total"}}]) more on this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: It's throwing an exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'

Comment: ah! sorry that's available only on or after 3.2 version

Comment: @KaSh there is lookup over lookup - so that is not implemented even in 3.2 :-)

Comment: thank you @profesor79 :) I was just trying to figure that in the shell and got the error.  (learnt something new today) I'd be very interested to know if there is a way to construct the query for this problem. over to you and other experts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following profesor79's advice to use three different calls, I put together this solution to get all the sub-events belonging to the user:

```
var userIds = db.users.find({"username":"userx"}).map(function(user) { 
  return user._id; 
});
var eventIds= db.events.find({userId: {$in:userIds}}).map(function(event) { 
  return event._id; 
});
db.subevents.find({eventId:{$in:eventIds}});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to make 3 ddifrent calls in mongo 3.0.7

1. GetUSerData
2. GetEventData
3. GetSubEventData

As you have relational schema here - this should be easy.

You could improve schema and remove subEvent collection by embedding subEvents documents into one events document

***EDIT***

```
/* Event */
{
    "_id" : "XjhAqqNBkezKY3mdN",
    "name" : "My event",
    "userId" : "FiKsAAAgBb7cNoPH7"
    "subewents" : [{
            "_id" : "WkYAqBXNpJryp7rum",
            "name" : "The subevent",
            "eventId" : "hQXNzX3jbWppbAYFH"
        }, {
            "_id" : "WkYAqBXNpJryp7rum2",
            "name" : "The subevent2",
            "eventId" : "hQXNzX3jbWppbAYFH"
        }, {
            "_id" : "WkYAqBXNpJryp7rum",
            "name" : "The subevent",
            "eventId" : "hQXNzX3jbWppbAYFH"
        }
    ]
}

/* User */
{
    "_id" : "RTHh5srhLMQp625zF",
    "username" : "userx"
}
```

Comment: So for example I should extract the eventIds into an array and then use that array to get the subEvent data? If it's not too much trouble, could you show us a little code sample?

Comment: @Cos - please see my edit with proposed structure - and could you tell me if this have a sense in your case

Comment: Thank you, however changing the schema is not an option for me at this point, I'd still be interested in the construction of the 3 different calls.